# React component for rendering a form based on data fetched from back-end not working

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I am trying to create a react component for rendering a form in react based on data that is fethced from a back-end app via API request . following code is the entire component:

```
const AnswerSchema = z.object({
    id: z.number(),
    answer: z.string().nullable(),
    rating: z.number().nullable(),
  });
  
  const QuestionSchema = z.object({
    id: z.number(),
    question: z.string(),
    description: z.string().nullable(),
    type: z.string(),
    answers: z.array(AnswerSchema),
  });
  
  const TemplateSchema = z.object({
    id: z.number(),
    title: z.string(),
    type: z.string(),
    study: z.string(),
    questions: z.array(QuestionSchema),
  });
  
  const FormEntrySchema = z.object({
    id: z.number(),
    currentPhase: z.string(),
    template: TemplateSchema,
  });
  
type FormEntryValues = z.infer<typeof FormEntrySchema>;

export function FormQuestionsForm() {
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const [defaultValues,setDefaultValues] = useState<Partial<FormEntryValues>>();
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
       const data = await formService.getFormsForInternshipByStudentId(1);
       setDefaultValues(data[0]);
    })();
  }, []);

  const form = useForm<FormEntryValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver (FormEntrySchema),
    defaultValues,
    mode: "onChange",
  });

  const { fields: questions } = useFieldArray({
    name: `template.questions`,
    control: form.control,
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
     (async () => {
       console.log(questions)
     })();
   }, [questions]);

  const useAnswersArray = (questionIndex: number) => {
    const { fields: answers, append: appendAnswer, remove: removeAnswer } = useFieldArray({
      name: `template.questions.${questionIndex}.answers`,
      control: form.control,
    });
  
    return { answers, appendAnswer, removeAnswer };
  };

  function onSubmit(data: FormEntryValues) {
    toast({
      title: "You submitted the following values:",
      description: (
        <pre className="mt-2 w-[340px] rounded-md bg-slate-950 p-4">
          <code className="text-white">{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</code>
        </pre>
      ),
    });
  }
  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="template.title"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
              <p>{field.value}</p>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        
        <div>
          {questions.map((question, index) => (
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              key={question.id}
              name={`template.questions.${index}.question`}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel className={cn(index !== 0 && "sr-only")}>
                    URLs
                  </FormLabel>
                  <FormDescription className={cn(index !== 0 && "sr-only")}>
                    Add links for the images
                  </FormDescription>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input {...question} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

I tried logging the 'defaultValues' and they get set correctly but when logging the 'answers' array (as shown in code) it just logs an empty array and I can't figure out why. The structure of the response is correct and 'template' has an 'answers' field ofcourse, so this is not the problem. Feel free to ask if I forgot to provide needed information. Thanks in advance for your time and help!

you can find more information about the form components a following link: https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/form